# How to built in if-condition based on group size in a pandas groupby object

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas, group-by

this question is probably simple, but I just can't figure out how to do it.
I have a dataframe grouped by a column. I want to plot each group, but only if its size is > 2.

```
Here is my code:
df1=df.groupby('Origin')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for key, group in df1:
        plt.figure()
        group.plot(x='xColumnr', y='yColumn', title=str(key))
```

I have tried to filter out these groups using `df2=df1.filter(lambda group: group.size() > 2)` and set df2 in place of df1 in my code, but that gets me the error `TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not callable`.
Then I tried

```
df3=df1.size()
if df3[df3 > 2]:
    plot stuff
```

which raises the exception 'True and False columns missing'.
How can I build in the if condition to plot only groups with a size > 2?

Comment: `group.size()` should be `group.size`, it's a property not a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to iterate through the dataset and decide if the groups have enough data or not:

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names = ['Bob','Jessica','Mary','John','Mel']
zipcode = [100, 100, 77, 77, 973]
weight = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]

BabyDataSet = zip(names,zipcode, weight)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = BabyDataSet, columns=['Name', 'Zipcode', 'Weight'])

grouped = df.groupby(df.Zipcode)

for key, group in grouped:
    entries = group.size
    columns = len(group.columns)
    if entries/columns >= 2:
        plt.figure()
        group.plot(x='Zipcode', y='Weight', title=str(key))
```

There probably is a much nicer way still though.

Example inspired by http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/01%20-%20Lesson.ipynb

Comment: Nice, works! But I don't understand why the `columns = len(group.columns)` is necessary...Could you explain that? Thanks!

Comment: That line is not necessary. One could as well just have used `len(group.columns)` directly. It's just there for better readability in the division.